# Why navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition doesn't work on IE 11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, safari, geolocation

just bought a new windows 8 pc with IE 11. When testing on this url:
http://www.pagesforbusiness.com/business-directory/wedding-accessories/
and press the button Show my position on map I get error that location can not be detected and second error "Internet Explorer stopped working" and needs to close the program. 
The strange thing is that same page working when I open it in my old laptop with windows 7 and same IE 11.. Also the code is working on Mozila and Chrome and of course not working on Safari..
My question is is this a bug in the code or problem with my new pc settings?
Also has anyone successed to make navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition working with Safari and Mobiles ? If yes, can you please provide link to working page where I can see that Safary may work with navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition
I hope to get help here, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for IE10 error causing to close the program. It was of course the IE default settings and I had to add this website http://www.pagesforbusiness.com into trusted sites section upon Privacy settings. This is really stupid because this way Microsoft kill browser integraded functionality and makes again IE as non functional browser. What is the sense to ask the visitor if he allows to detect his position if deep inside in the setting some setting blocks the user to share his position. Isn't it stupid? Now the problem is how to make user to add the site to trusted sites in order to share his location?